# Grunt and CasperJS Testing - No exit or termination (only with CTRL+C) on Windows

Tags: windows, gruntjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I'll try to setup an testing environment with CasperJS and grunt. Everything is working as expected and the testing is working well.

I have only one problem. I have to press CTRL+C in the terminal to exit the test. This is a big problem, when I run this task in a CI tool such as Jenkins because the CasperJS/PhantomJS process is blocking the grunt process and therefore the build will never be successful.

Has someone any idea how to solve this problem?

Casper-Test-File:

```
var config = require('../../config.json');

casper.test.begin("Testing Homepage QuoteBox", 0, function suite(test){

    casper.start(config.url);

    casper.then(function() {});

    casper.then(function() {});

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
        this.exit();
        phantom.exit();
    });

});
```

GruntFile.js:

```
casper : {
    yourTask : {
        options : {
            test : true,
            'log-level' : 'error',
            'fail-fast' : true,
            'ignore-ssl-errors' : 'yes',
            'load-images' : 'no',
            'verbose': 'no',
            concise : true
        },
        files : {
            'xunit/casper-results.xml' : [ 'front-end-test/casper/**/*.js' ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a gradle build script to execute grunt with npm. I installed python on the local machine. I haven't worked on this task the last days but last thing I discovered was that python running on windows has a bug which causes the problem that scripts not terminate.

Comment: I also have the problem, when I running it manually in a git bash on windows 7. I am not sure. Next step is to try it on one of our staging servers which are linux machines in AWS. I'll keep you in a loop about results, but would be nice to get some suggestions or guesses what causes this problem. Especially, when this is really a bug using the combination python and windows and node.js.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cheers, i'll try this and report the result.

Comment: I'll check the PATH environment and everything was fine. If I am execute the casperJS script with SlimerJS everything was fine. So I start searching the problem in phantom. I started the phantomJS as standalone application and tried to use phantom.exit() method. Result was the same as in the gradle + grunt build environment. So I started to find the problem in phantomJS and here we go - this is happening when you have a NVidea GF 620 or similar. I tried my setup in a virtual machine with windows, and on physical machines with Debian Linux and OS X. Everything works fine.

Comment: The problem is solved in PhantomJS 2.0 or look into one of these threads 
https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=845
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11661
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10845

Comment: You can delete your comments now and if you want add some of their information to the question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll checked the PATH environment and everything was fine. If I am execute the casperJS script with SlimerJS everything works fine. 
So I start searching the problem in phantom. I started the phantomJS as standalone application and tried to use phantom.exit() method. Result was the same as in the gradle + grunt build environment. So I started to find the problem in phantomJS and here we go - this is happening when you have a Nvidia GF 620 or similar. I tried my setup in a virtual machine with windows, and on physical machines with Debian Linux and OS X. Everything works fine.

The problem is solved in PhantomJS 2.0 for Phantom 1.X versions look at

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10845

or use google and search for "PhantomJS Nvidia exit"